# Discordjs check if a user has a role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this code which works fine, I just need to check if a user has a role, it logs all the users, with their id, discriminator and username exc. I just can't get the roles. Can you guys please help?

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.username}`);

    var Count;
    for(Count in client.users.array()){
       var User = client.users.array()[Count];
       if(User.username == "someUsername"){
         //User.sendMessage("you");
       }
       //User.checkRole("Admin");

    }
}
```

`checkRole()` function is something that I made up. I jsut need some help.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.username}`);

    var Count;
    for(Count in client.users.array()){
       var User = client.users.array()[Count];
       if(User.hasRole("Admin")){
          console.log(User.username);
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: What? You can't access a user's roles via their `User` object. You get that from a `guildMember` object. What if a user is in 3 servers. Do you think they'd have the same roles in all 3

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking, thanks for the answer @Wright

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access roles you must approach it by guild, *not* user. (As mentioned by @Wright)

I'd do this using a map to save all the guild members, and then going through each member (that way when you come across one with a specific role name, you still have acess to the guildobject (as it is a guildmember object)

```
m = client.guilds.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.members;
});
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    console.log("\n\nNew Guild: ");        
    console.log(m[i].map(function (obj) {
        return obj.guild.name + " , " + obj.user.username + "  :  " + obj._roles;
    }).join('\n'));
}
```

The output I get with this is (I censored out username's):
[image: Output]

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get the emails of the users?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
// assuming role.id is an actual ID of a valid role:
if(message.member.roles.has(role.id)) {
  // user has that role
} else {
  //user doesn't have that role
}
```

https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/information/understanding-roles.html

Comment: The thing is, what's the message variable there? I don't want get the user Role on a message, I want to get it as soon as the client bot is ready @DiegoFrancisco

Comment: @turmuka could you provide more code so can I understand better?

Comment: please check my new update, there is no `message` object, so it is undefined. I know I can use `client.on('message', (message))` but that is not what I want to do. I want to get user roles under `client.on('ready', ())` @DiegoFrancisco

Comment: It looks like currently discord.js doesn't have a way to get an user's role without accessing to the messages.

Comment: @DiegoFrancisco that last comment is incorrect. You can access the guilds object.